# New twitter widget in IOS6 HTML5 web app triggers keyboard on startup

Tags: html, twitter, ios6, iphone-standalone-web-app

I'm building a HTML5 digital magazine and embedded the (new) Twitter widget. When I add the digital magazine to my homescreen as a web app on an 'iDevice' (iPhone/iPad) with IOS6, there is a glitch when starting the web app; The app loads, but when the Twitter widget is loaded, it somehow focusses on an input(?) form element, triggering the iDevice's keyboard. When the app is loaded, the keyboard is still shown.

For the iPad, this is only annoying: for the iPhone, the viewport is zoomed leaving my web app in an undesired state.

Has anybody had the same problem and somehow disabled the 'focus' on the Twitter widget triggering the keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guys from Twitter changed the behavior of the widget, solving the bug as described above.

Ref: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/12858#comment-28613